# I dont know why I'm getting this error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

I am trying to multiply each sub array with -1, but I am getting this index error.
I specifically put the "if i!=len(A)" to solve this error but Im still getting it

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
for i in range(len(A)):
    if i!= len(A):
        A[i]*=-1
        A[i+1]*=-1
    
    else:
      A[0]*=-1
      A[-1]*=-1

print(A)
```

```
# The error message is




IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 5
      3 if i!= len(A):
      4     A[i]*=-1
----> 5     A[i+1]*=-1
      6 else:
      7     A[0]*=-1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `len(A)` is 5, but the case causing the error is `i == 4`. You need to adjust that check to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to multiply every element in your list by -1 you can simply try:

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
for i in range(len(A)):
  A[i]*=-1

print(A)
```

Comment: I am trying to multiply every two elements in the list with -1 for every iteration